# gtk.h not found

Tags: autocompletion

I am now using `vi` to edit a `Gtk` program in `C`. I can compile it easily using the command:

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gtk gtk.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

There is no problem doing this. But when I am editing it in `vi`, there are lots of errors (I am using `ycmd` for auto-completion):

[image]

and the first error being `<gtk/gtk.h> not found`. If I change it to `<gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>` it will work, but it has problem in the header `gtk.h` itself, like it can't find `<gdk/gdk.h>`. Can anyone tell me how to solve this? Thanks.

***EDIT:*** I use the following flags in the `.ycm_extra_conf.py`:

[image: second]

But in the end it also has these errors:

[image: thrid]

Comment: What does your `.ycm_extra_conf.py` look like?

Comment: There is no such file. But I do find one in the `example` folder of the `ycm` module. Do you mean that I should use that example, place in my working directory and use it as config for `ycmd`?

Comment: You should read YCM's documentation.

Comment: Maybe yes. I copied the `conf` into my `cwd` and it worked. But there are other errors.

Comment: So `ycm` should magically guess what your paths are, even if you have to specify them to `gcc` explicitly ? Reading the docs is mandatory.

Comment: `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` outputs a lot more than what you have included here.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. So you mean that I should include *everything* output by `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`?